# How can I remove default filters and add new filters in sale orders search menu(view name : sale.order.search.inherit.sale)

Tags: xml, odoo-10

Version : odoo 10 
Original file :(sale_views.xml)

```
<record id="sale_order_view_search_inherit_sale" model="ir.ui.view">
<field name="name">sale.order.search.inherit.sale</field>
<field name="model">sale.order</field>
<field name="mode">primary</field>
<field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_sales_order_filter"/>
<field name="arch" type="xml">
    <xpath expr="//filter[@name='my_sale_orders_filter']"     position="after">
        <separator/>
        <filter string="Sales" name="sales" domain="[('state','in',('progress','done'))]" />
        <separator/>
        <filter string="To Invoice" domain="[('invoice_status','=','to invoice')]" />
        <filter string="Upselling" domain="[('invoice_status','=','upselling')]" />
    </xpath>
</field>
</record>
```

What should I do while inheriting this view?
How can I remove or hide all the default filters?
There is a problem replacing filter string....I tried just like this:

```
<xpath expr="//filter[@string='Upselling']" position="replace"/>
```

But got an error like this:

> View inheritance may not use attribute 'string' as a selector.

Is there a solution?

Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 2):

Try the xpath with the domain. The error is raised because strings attributes defined in xml nodes are susceptible of being translated and your xpath should be targeting the same string in multiple langs and that is not supported.

Something like this should work:

```
<xpath expr="//filter[@domain='[(\'invoice_status\',\'=\',\'upselling\')]']" position="replace"/>
```

or more simple:

```
<filter domain="[('invoice_status','=','upselling')]" position="replace"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to remove a filter in inherited view,

```html
 <xpath expr="//filter[@name='filter_name']" position="replace"/>
```